# Multiple dynamic dataLists and chrome

Tags: google-chrome, dynamic-data-list

Running chrome 58.0.3029.110 under Linux similar issue reported under windows.

Data List dynamic (provided through websocket).

When attempting to hit a page with multiple dataLists none of the dataLists fill in.

At the time I found local solution was to simply switch from person 1 to person 2.

Whilst this appears to fix the issue for me this isn't exactly advice I can start handing out to users who so wish to use my site.

I have spent a good few hours trying to locate where the issue is and have found if i have only 1 instance of datalist on that page and under the broken profile . (aka Person 1) the data list appears to work absolutely fine:

```
<input name="something" list="someresults"/>
<datalist id="someresults"></datalist>
```

Working fine, I can change above to any of the datalists on the page and all works correctly.

The moment I start using a second dataList on the same page:

```
  <input name="something" list="someresults"/>
    <datalist id="someresults"></datalist>
   <input name="something2" list="someresults2"/>
    <datalist id="someresults2"></datalist>
```

Neither of them will load the content, the arrow fills up to say content, having a look within html the DOM has been updated with the user input matching results.

Just scratching my head as to what on earth can cause this its obviously not the code since as i say by changing chrome profiles the issue goes away.

Any insight / fix information will be much appreciated

PS process is rather complex if required I can create a few demo pages on the live site to show the problem at hand since I think the actual workings too complex to post all on here

Answer (score 0):

In this case it turned out to be due to two things, maybe my own summary helped narrow it down a lot quicker.

1. Disable the main form : (if used in main form remove it)

`autocomplete="off"`

2. Disable the same tag used in any dataList inputs: (remove tag)
   `autocomplete="off"`

Please note with single dataList and autocomplete="off" on a given field was workng fine.

(really strange)